# log de IIS fallo Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13] JwtBearerOptions

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, jwt, kestrel

Al examinar una API publicada en IIS me da el siguiente error:

```
    Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: C:\inetpub\My_API
Now listening on: http://127.0.0.1:44674
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
      Connection id "0HM9MTIMQIFTF", Request id "0HM9MTIMQIFTF:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.ArgumentNullException: String reference not set to an instance of a String.
Parameter name: s
   at System.Text.Encoding.GetBytes(String s)
   at My_API.Startup.<ConfigureServices>b__4_2(JwtBearerOptions options) in D:\repos\API\My_API\Startup.cs:line 173
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigureNamedOptions`1.Configure(String name, TOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.<Get>b__0()
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
   at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache`1.GetOrAdd(String name, Func`1 createOptions)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.Get(String name)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.InitializeAsync(AuthenticationScheme scheme, HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandlerProvider.GetHandlerAsync(HttpContext context, String authenticationScheme)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
Application is shutting down...
```

En el archivo Startup.cs, el código de la línea que genera el error es el siguiente:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options => 
options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
      {
          ValidateIssuer = false,
          ValidateAudience = false,
          //ValidateLifetime = false,
          ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
          //ValidIssuer = "https://locahost",
          //ValidAudience = "https://localhost",
          IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Key_Token"])),
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
      });
```

Ejecutando la API en desarrollo no da ningún problema, la autenticación se realiza sin problemas pero al ejecutar la API en producción, el servidor responde con un status 500.

Si alguien puede ayudarme a ver el problema.

Gracias por todo.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado la solución a mi problema.
El error se producía debido a que la key para generar el token JWT no la estaba encontrando desde el Startup.cs. En el entorno de desarrollo, la clave la tenía guardada dentro de una variable de entorno del proyecto, en el archivo *appLaunchSettings.json*, pero al pasarlo a un entorno de producción esta clave no se encontraba dentro del archivo *appSettings.json*, por lo que en el *StartUp.cs* daba el error al no encotrarla.
Para solucionarlo, he guardado las variables creadas en el archivo *appLaunchSettings.json* en el archivo *appSettings.json* y ahora todo funciona.

Gracias.